# SharePoint 2016 Edition,

Tags: development, 2016

Inside my SharePoint 2016 project,I want to programmaticlly check the SharePoint 2016 edition **(standard - enterprise - foundation)**.

I've found the SharePoint version But I would like to have SharePoint 2016 edition  using c#.

Please help me with sample code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can simply get the SharePoint 2016 Edition using C# as the following:**

**First** Add the below reference to your solution

- Microsoft.SharePoint
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration

**Second**, include the below namespaces

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
```

**Third**, use the below code to get the Sharepoint 2016 Edition based on its corresponding GUID

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm spfarm = SPFarm.Local;
string editionguid = spfarm.Products.Last().ToString();
string edition = "";

   if (editionguid == "5db351b8-c548-4c3c-bfd1-82308c9a519b")
      {
         edition = "SharePoint Server 2016 Trail";
      }
   else if (editionguid == "4F593424-7178-467A-B612-D02D85C56940")
      {
          edition = "SharePoint Server 2016 Standard";
      }
   else if (editionguid == "716578d2-2029-4ff2-8053-637391a7e683")
      {
          edition = "SharePoint Server 2016 Enterprise";
      }
   else
      {
        edition = "it's not SharePoint 2016";
      }
```

**By the way,** I tried the above code in two different farms (SharePoint 2016) that worked properly

---

Also, To get the GUID, you can use the below SharePoint PowerShell cmdlet

```
(Get-SPFarm).Products
```

In Sharepoint 2016, The result of the above cmdlet show two GUID.
The last GUID refers to your SharePoint 2016 Edition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below property to find the build version number

```
SPFarm.Local.BuildVersion;
```

If it starts with `16.0` that means its SharePoint 2016

Edition information is stored in registry path - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server 
Extensions\16.0\WSS\InstalledProducts`

Then look for GUID's to check the proper edition

```
5DB351B8-C548-4C3C-BFD1-82308C9A519B = SharePoint 2016 Trail
716578D2-2029-4FF2-8053-637391A7E683 = SharePoint 2016 Enterprise
4F593424-7178-467A-B612-D02D85C56940 = SharePoint 2016 Standard
```

Try this 2010 codebase - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff721969.aspx and update it using above information

Comment: Yes i know that , i said in my question I can get the version but I would like to get the SharePoint 2016 edition Is it standard or enterprise or foundation ?

Comment: @Aashirya please see my updated answer